# Spacing for Loquat trees

Tags: trees, pruning, spacing

The previous owners of my property left me three young loquat trees. They are all in the same planter, and are much closer to structures (and to each other) than most advice I see online at 8' from the house and 3' from the nearest fence.

Two questions on these:

1. Should I remove the two smaller trees to let the biggest one have the space?
2. Is it feasible to prune the tree(s) and keep it(them) from damaging the fence or house while still growing large enough to bear at least some fruit?

Note: The large trunk in the middle of the picture is a stump from whatever was there before. The loquats are the three smaller trunks that surround it. This is just to get a sense of scale and spacing.

[image]

Comment: I always KIS (keep it simple) when it comes to stuff like this. Don't try to address a non-existent issue. If the tree's are fine then leave them be (if you like them) otherwise; if you have a problem, then it might be worth addressing.

Comment: @Rob you’re probably right - I’ve been kicking this down the road so far! But I ask now because any likely problem is probably easier to deal with now when they’re smaller.